# Update com join MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com dados de clientes, com os campos 'nomecorretor' e 'codcorretor'.
Preciso atualizar o 'codcorretor' a partir dos dados da minha tabela usuario, onde tenho 'nome' e 'codusuario'.
De maneira que fique algo do tipo `codcorretor=codusuario where nomecorretor=nome`

Tentei fazer assim mas não rolou:

```
update clientes set cli.codcorretor=us.codusuario
inner join usuario us on cli.nomecorretor=us.nome
where us.codusuario in (select codusuario from usuario);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nos `UPDATE`s com `JOIN`, os `JOIN`s devem vir antes do `SET`. Logo, a sua query ficaria assim::

```
update clientes
inner join usuario us on cli.nomecorretor = us.nome
set cli.codcorretor = us.codusuario
where us.codusuario in (select codusuario from usuario);
```

Comment: Deu certo, só precisei alterar o encoding pra `utf8_general_ci` e funcionou ! Muito obrigada !